# Responsive "Full Div" YouTube video

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

Is there a way to put an **YouTube** video in a div background, like the [following](https://www.imi21.com/background-video-full-screen.php) site does with a `<video>` tag, the video "**covering**" the div (that is, no empty spaces left, keeping the original ratio)?

Knowing that the recommended way to display a YouTube video actually in HTML5 is an iframe:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```

[image]

I tried to simulate the same behavior on [this codePen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/qxypPR).

Comment: How about `height: 100%; width: 100%;` and `margin: 0;` on the `#video`? That'll cover everything unless other blocks are pushing it away, is that your real issue?

Comment: The video should Cover the Div....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

#myBtn {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi pro.</p>
  <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Pause</button>
</div>

<script>
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function myFunction() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    video.pause();
    btn.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but it was about YouTube, the mp4 video sample is already present in the linked OP page

Comment: is pretty good as solution, your second link, but just there is a top menu problem... You can see in the OP picture, there is a white menu in page top... this one breaks the logic, as you case see here: https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/XZBYea?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZBVvN

```
#video{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 0;
}
#videoMessage{
   color:white;    
   position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: is there a way do not let the empty spaces, keeping the original ratio